# Why is "ille" used in Winnie ille Pu and Hobbitus Ille?

Tags: contemporary-latin, pronouns, articles, translation-explanation

I learned early on that Latin has no articles.  So why is it, then, that *Winnie the Pooh* and *The Hobbit* are translated *Winnie ille Pu* and *Hobbitus Ille*?

Wouldn't it be more correct to not translate the article?  What is the justification for including *ille* in these book titles?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's true that in Classical Latin, *ille* is a demonstrative pronoun (corresponding to *that*), not an article; indeed, articles as we know them in English do not exist in Classical Latin.  However, that's not the entire story.

## *Ille* in Classical Latin

The meaning of *ille* in Classical Latin is not so narrow as to exclude its use in these book titles.  Allen and Greenough describe the "honorific" *ille* as follows:

> It is sometimes used [...] (usually following its noun) of what is *famous* or *well-known*<sup>1</sup>

Similarly, Gildersleeves includes the following usage:

> That which is well known, notorious (often put after the substantive): **tēstula illa**, *that* (notorious) *potsherd* [...] **illud Solōnis**, *that* (famous saying) *of Solon's*.<sup>2</sup>

So we can see that even in classical Latin, using *ille* in these book titles can indicate the notoriety of the Pooh and the Hobbit in question.  This is similar to the sense in English of saying "Not just any hobbit, but *that* hobbit" to identify a well-known one.

## *Ille* in Late Latin

Following the Classical period, *ille* quickly began to be used more distinctly as a definite article, more like *the* in English.  One of the earliest examples of this appears in the [*Peregrinatio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egeria_(pilgrim)):

> But already in the fourth century, the author of the *Pilgrimage to Holy Places* had begun to employ *ille* as a definite article: *toti illi montes*, she wrote, meaning "all the mountains," not, as would have been the case with a writer of Classical Latin, "all those mountains."<sup>3</sup>

By the 6th century, this usage was apparently common: [Gregory of Tours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_of_Tours) used *ille* as a definite article "almost as freely" as the articles in modern Romance languages are used.<sup>4</sup>  An 8th-century example of this is [Hygeburg's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygeburg) *Vita sancti Willibaldi*.<sup>5</sup>

## *Pooh* and *Hobbit*

The use of *ille* in these book titles can be defended in Classical Latin as emphasizing how well-known the protagonists are.  And if that justification is for whatever reason unsatisfactory,<sup>6</sup> we can appeal to the usage of *ille* as a definite article in Late Latin.

---

**References and notes:**

1. *New Latin Grammar*, [page 178, §297](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q7cAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA178)
2. *Latin Grammar*, [page 193, §307](https://books.google.com/books?id=UU0BIAbE0SIC&pg=PA193)
3. Joseph Solodow, *Latin Alive*, [page 239](https://books.google.com/books?id=2OfV9NZxH68C&pg=PA239).  See also the following citation for more on this work.
4. Edward Bechtel, "Sanctae Silviae Peregrinatio" in *Studies in Classical Philology*, Volume 4, [page 144](https://books.google.com/books?id=5-rfAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA144)
5. James Clackson, [*A Companion to the Latin Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=skiGGCK_JAIC&pg=RA2-PT286)
6. I've seen it argued that the *ille* in *Hobbitus Ille* unduly emphasizes the importance of Bilbo, given Tolkien's pains to portray him as a typical hobbit.  I'm not convinced (surely Bilbo turns out to be a very *atypical* hobbit), but even admitting this argument, the author of *Hobbitus Ille*, [to put it generously](http://www.theonering.net/torwp/2013/03/24/70159-reviewed-hobbitus-ille/), does not appear to have attempted to translate into high Classical Latin.  Instead he adopts a more accessible style that borrows some aspects of Late Latin, and on that basis *ille* in the title could be defended.

Comment: Another example from Classical Latin: [*Antipater ille Sidonius*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0120%3Abook%3D3%3Asection%3D194) (Cicero).

Answer (score 5):

I think rather, that this "ille" is the translation of Mileny´s joke: As Christopher Robins father objects, tat he schould not call him "winnie", because he was a boy, Christopher Robin answers that therefore he calls him Winnie *the* Pooh. "Don´t You know, what "the" means?"
Greetings,

Manuel Haus