# He is known for...?

Tags: idiom

How would one best translate the English idiom "to be known for", as in "he is known for defeating the Gauls"? This came up when discussing uses of the gerund, but in English the idiom also works with a non-verbal noun, as in "he is known for his strength".

(The obvious solution is a literal translation, with the passive of *scīre*, but the English feels too idiomatic for that. Another option would be an adjective like *clarus*, but I'd like to know if there's an idiom or commonly used expression for this.)

Comment: I would use *notus* for "known". My first guess is *notus est pro X*, but it sounds fishy.

Comment: My guess would be something like *Gallos vicisse notus est* 'he is known to have defeated the Gauls'.

Comment: Perhaps *notus* + ablative of respect, rather than *pro*? Not sure if that's attested but I know *clarus* can take it.

Comment: My uninformed guess is that there is an appropriate idiom using "fama"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> "he is known for defeating the Gauls"

***victoriā belli gallici praeclarus est***

[***Clarus***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dclarus) or [***praeclarus***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=praeclarus&highlight=praeclarus)
are the way to go, especially in a good sense. There are a zillion examples. *Notus* is really still only the participle of *nosco,* without the connotation of *to be known for.*

An ablative is the most common case, but other constructions exist: e.g. genitive: *T. Livius, eloquentiae ac fidei praeclarus in primis,* (Tac. A. 4, 34); or *in* + Abl. *multi praeclari in philosophiā et nobiles,* (Cic. de Or. 1, 11, 46)

As for translating “for defeating the Gauls” with *victoriā belli gallici,* it is a matter of taste. Latin privileges *nomina actionis* in such constructions, and e.g. Suetonius wrote *in victoriā belli civilis* (Suet. Caes. 75), “when he won the civil war.”

[***Famōsus***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfamosus) is also an option, also with ablative, but it is used much more in a bad sense *(infamous)* than in a good one. In present-day Italian it’s only used in a good sense, and it’s a *famosus* false friend.

Comment: What about something in the line of *ille victor gallicorum*. Not sure if idiomatic, but the point is ille+title

Comment: Not exactly what I thought, but _ille_ arguably works. See [this](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2/why-is-ille-used-in-winnie-ille-pu-and-hobbitus-ille) question and answer.