# Have Late Latin texts using "ipse, ipsa, ipsum" as definite articles been found?

Tags: late-latin, text-corpus, articles, demonstrative-adjective

This [anwser](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/3/6540) gives some examples of Late Latin texts using *ille, illa, illud* in ways quite similar to the usage of definite articles in modern Romance languages. However, I know that in some varieties of modern Romance languages, such as Sardinian or some varieties of Catalan, definitive articles derive from Latin *ipse, ipsa, ipsum*.

So, my question is: have some instances of Late Latin texts using *ipse, ipsa, ipsum* as definite articles been found?

Answer (score 0):

The *Peregrinatio* referred to in the answer you linked to does also use *ipse* in the way you describe. [The Wikipedia article on Egeria](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egeria_(pilgrim)) references this, and it has a link to the actual text as well.

Note 8 in [the notes to that text](https://web.archive.org/web/20041205093555/http://www.orbilat.com/Languages/Latin_Vulgar/Texts/Peregrinatio_Aetheriae.html) covers *ipse*.

Comment: Interesting. This text has one instance of such usage: "[...], et inde totum per mediam uallem **ipsam**, qua iacet in longo, rediremus ad iter cum hominibus Dei, qui nobis singula loca, quae scripta sunt, per ipsam uiallem ostendebant, sicut et factum est". Are there other texts whith some more instances?